# CSS transitions causing ul columns to break

Tags: css, transition

I am trying to create a page for employee profiles, where the image name and title are displayed, then clicking an arrow expands a description for that employee.

While I have everything working having my ul set to 2 columns is leading to a problem where expanding multiple descriptions slowly pushes the bottom li in that column onto the next. Potentially ending up with half an li on the next column.

Like this:
[image]

Ideally what would happen is the ul would just expand its height to account for the extra heights from the descriptions. However pushing the whole li onto the next column as soon as it starts to overlap would also be acceptable.

Is there any way to achieve this? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns02y1jq/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="teams">
    <li>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="imageWrap">
                <img src="useruploads/user.png">
            </div>

            <div class="details">
                <h2>Employee Name</h2>
                <h4>Title</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom">
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.teams {
margin: 1em auto;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
columns: 2;
max-width: 1024px;
}

.teams li {
padding: 1em;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.teams li .top {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
align-items: center;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.teams li .imageWrap {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background: #f3f3f3;
border-radius: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.teams li .imageWrap img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 1em;
box-sizing: border-box;
object-fit: cover;
break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.teams li .imageWrap:before {
content: "";
display: block;
padding-top: 100%;
}

.teams li .details {
margin-left: 1em;
width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

.teams li .top h2, 
.teams li .top h4 {
margin: 0;
color: #5A96D3;
}

.teams li .bottom {
margin-top: 1em;
opacity: 0;
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 0;
background: #f3f3f3;
transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
}

.teams li .bottom p {
margin: 0;
padding: 1em;
box-szing: border-box;
}

.teams li .bottom#expanded {
opacity: 1;
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 100px;
transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
}

.teams li .expander {
border-radius: 100%;
background: #f3f3f3;
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
padding: 0.5em;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}

.teams li .expander span {
text-align: center;
display: block;
user-select: none;
transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.teams li .expander#closed > span {
transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.teams li .expander#open > span {
transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset `display` and `width` to avoid `li` boxes to break into 2 columns :

exemple:

```js
$(".expander").click(function() {
  if($(this).attr("id") == "open") {
    $(this).attr("id", "closed");
    $(this).closest("li").find(".bottom").attr("id", "");
  }
  else {
    $(this).attr("id", "open");
    $(this).closest("li").find(".bottom").attr("id", "expanded");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.teams {
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    columns: 2;
    max-width: 1024px;
}

.teams li {
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 1em;  
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

.teams li .top {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.teams li .imageWrap {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.teams li .imageWrap img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    object-fit: cover;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.teams li .imageWrap:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}

.teams li .details {
    margin-left: 1em;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

.teams li .top h2, 
.teams li .top h4 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #5A96D3;
}

.teams li .bottom {
    margin-top: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
}

.teams li .bottom p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    box-szing: border-box;
}

.teams li .bottom#expanded {
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 100px;
    transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
}

.teams li .expander {
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.teams li .expander span {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    user-select: none;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.teams li .expander#closed > span {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.teams li .expander#open > span {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="teams">
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You may also try `break-inside:avoid;`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside

```js
$(".expander").click(function() {
  if($(this).attr("id") == "open") {
    $(this).attr("id", "closed");
    $(this).closest("li").find(".bottom").attr("id", "");
  }
  else {
    $(this).attr("id", "open");
    $(this).closest("li").find(".bottom").attr("id", "expanded");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.teams {
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    columns: 2;
    max-width: 1024px;
}

.teams li {
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    break-inside: avoid;/* here */
}

.teams li .top {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.teams li .imageWrap {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.teams li .imageWrap img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    object-fit: cover;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.teams li .imageWrap:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}

.teams li .details {
    margin-left: 1em;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

.teams li .top h2, 
.teams li .top h4 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #5A96D3;
}

.teams li .bottom {
    margin-top: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
}

.teams li .bottom p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.teams li .bottom#expanded {
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 100px;
    transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
}

.teams li .expander {
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.teams li .expander span {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    user-select: none;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.teams li .expander#closed > span {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.teams li .expander#open > span {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="teams">
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="imageWrap">
        <img src="useruploads/user.png">
      </div>
      
      <div class="details">
        <h2>Employee Name</h2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="expander"><span><</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `flex` to solve this a better way Update below CSS

```
.teams {
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    columns: 2;
    max-width: 1024px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.teams li {
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    flex: 1;
}
```

you can set `min-height` on `.teams li` if you know you description lines

Comment: Although this works great, I don't want the li opposite the one I have expanded the description for to also adjust its height, as happens with this example. I prefer how only one column is affected, as with the accepted answer. But I think both are good depending on how you want things to behave. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @EdwardHall i thought your cards act as row that's why i do that but any how G-Cyr solution is column wise which you want! Cheers for up-vote my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you display it from CSS

```
     $(".expander").click(function() {
         if($(this).attr("id") == "open") {
           $(this).attr("id", "closed");
           $("#" + Title).css("display", "none");
            }
            else {
              $(this).attr("id", "open");
              $("#" + Title).css("display", "block");
             }
```